# embed ng-src not changing dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Any ideas why dynamic src change doesn't work?

HTML:

```
<ul class="list-inline padding-vertical">
    <li ng-repeat="file in vm.files track by $index">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-bind="::file.title" ng-click="vm.OpenPDF(file.src)"></button>
    </li>
</ul>

<embed ng-src="{{ vm.src }}" width="100%" height="100%" alt=”pdf” pluginspage=”http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/readstep2.html”>
```

JavaScript:

```
function OpenPDF(file) {

    vm.src = 'files/' + $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(file);

}
```

It displays the initial value, but when changing the url, it doesn't change the content of `embed` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

From the controller it should be:

```
$scope.vm.OpenPDF = function (file) {
    vm.src = 'files/' + $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(file);
}
```

And I don't think `$sce.trustAsResourceUrl` is required because that shoudl be a local file not a remote one.

Comment: If I don't use `$sce.trustAsResourceUrl` it gives me `$sce` related error.
`$scope` isn't required anymore since I'm using a controller alias? therefore I'm referencing the controller variables/functions using `this`